# native node.js: how to include css?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Much of this has been discussed but in relation to express. I'm wondering how could I display a simple HTML with .css and some image in native node.js?

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="imgs/image.jpeg" />
</body>
</html>
```

And here's what I got so far:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if (req.url === '/hi') {
        res.write('hi');
        res.end();
    } else if (req.url === '/bye') {
        res.write('bye');
        res.end();
    } else {    
        fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, file){
            res.write(file);
            res.end();      
        });
    }

}).listen(3000);
```

Also, I don't exactly understand why I get two requests for the same image?

```
/
/css/style.css
/imgs/image.jpeg
/imgs/image.jpeg
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having with this code? What do you mean by "external CSS"?

Comment: OK, I got that part wrong, I meant the css which is part of the HTML, I host both of course. I have edited the title. The problem is, the page does not load css nor image.

Comment: You only configured your server to respond with `index.html` `hi` and `bye`, so when your browser requests css, the server sends it html.

Comment: You need that application to provide static routing to all files of the web site. Creating an HTTP server won't do that alone.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is basically creating a server, similar to Apache or another application which serves data to requests. You set up routes to handle `/hi`, `/bye`, and respond with a default page if anything else is requested. When the browser requests your CSS file, it's responding with that default page.

You need to add a route to deliver your CSS file, just like you have routes to deliver the other stuff. You're programming a server when you use Node.js. Anything that's served to the client needs to be handled by your code.

Comment: OK, but this doesn't quite explain why I get TWO requests for the same image? Also, can you please provide a sample of how to return CSS? I'll figure out the rest. Thank you.

Comment: @uglycode: My guess for the image stuff is that when your browser requests the / route, it gets your default HTML file, which links to the image. When it requests the CSS file, it receives the HTML file again. The HTML file links to the image, so it tries to load the image again. You return CSS the same way you're returning a HTML here. You set up a route for the CSS, and you read the file and return it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
    <!-- this forks a request for a css file --> 

</head>
<body>
    <img src="imgs/image.jpeg" />
</body>
</html>
```

and In your server you only serve `/hi`, `/bye` and `index.html` and it'll fall back to `index.html`

```
else {    
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, file){
        res.write(file);
        res.end();      
    });
}
```

try using devTools to watch the request and its response.
or try getting `http://localhost:3000/css/style.css` this will return the index.html

try loading `http://localhost:3000/blah/blah` this will return index.html.

there is a lot more to add the the response type and if the path exists. (404)

[Look at this package](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server) as an example on serving static files. there are also tons of frameworks (Express, Sails, SocketStream, Koa ...)